# The delete_posts capability?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

Shouldn't this remove the capability to delete a post? Even if I remove the delete_posts capability for an editor, he still can trash a post and then delete i permanently. That can't be right.

How do you remove the capability to trash/delete a post?

Comment: Nice with a down vote. Even nicer with an explanation.

Comment: There are other, related capabilities which you might want to remove (delete_published_posts for example, see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table). I don't know why you need this but make sure that you remove and keep the right set of capabilities (e.g. forbid deleting others or published posts but allow deleting own, unpublished one).

Comment: I want to remove the capability for editors to trash/delete posts. And by removing delete_posts, that should affect the other capabilities to such as delete_published_posts etc. But there is no documentation on this, just me thinking that would be the most obvious way for capabilities to work.

Comment: But event if i remove all capabilities (delete_posts, delete_others_posts, delete_published_posts and delete_private_posts) the editor can still trash/delete posts.

Comment: I've solved it for now by hiding Elements via CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this was some conflict plugin/functions.php/theme/WP-version...

I just duplicated the editor role with [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/), removed all the `delete_*_posts` capabilities and the user **cannot** delete a post.

[image]